# Visual Studio Code PHP autocomplete on external librarys

Tags: php, autocomplete, editor, visual-studio-code

I use the IDE Visual Studio Code to write scripts in PHP. To write plugins in PHP for a store system, I need to add an external library to my worktree. I have already cloned the library from github and added the folder to my workspace where I am working on the plugin.

The problem is that my IDE still gives errors that namespaces and classes can't be loaded because, for example, there is no namespace with that name. I also can't use the autocomplete feature.

Can someone explain me how to fix this problem?

Screenshots:
[Undefined Type [...]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d53d.png)

Comment: please add screenshots and texts of error messages

Comment: I added a Screenshot, but nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem now! **To fix this problem I needed the vscode plugin "Intelephense".**

In VSCODE: right click on the folder where the interface must be used and click on "**Folder Settings**". In the second row under the intelephense extension the radio button "**Intelephense > Environment: Include Paths**" is shown. There I had to add the path to the interface.